# Artifacts are not pulled in a child pipeline

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

This is my gitlab ci config. In the build stage the application is build in the `dist`folder, which is stored as an artifact.
The next deploy stage is a trigger to run a child pipeline for the deployment.

But the `dist` artifacts aren't pulled for the child pipeline, so the child job fails.

1. How do I get the `dist` artifacts in the child job?
2. Even if the child deploy job fails, the parent pipeline shows a complete pass. I would expect to see, that at least one child has failed.

**.gitlab-ci.yml**

```
stages:
  - build
  - deployment

build:
  stage: build
  cache:
    key: ${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}
    policy: pull
    paths:
      - node_modules/
  artifacts:
    when: always
    paths:
      - deployment.yml
      - dist/
  script:
    - node ./build-app.js # creates dist folder
    - node ./generate-pipeline.js # generates deployment.yml

trigger-deploy:
  stage: deployment
  trigger:
    include:
      - artifact: deployment.yml
        job: build
```

**deployment.yml**

```
stages:
  - deploy

app1-deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - ls dist # fails, as dist folder is not existing
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'trigger-deploy' job needs a [dependency](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#dependencies) of the 'build' job, to allow the artifacts to be providable.

To get the parent to fail when the child pipeline fails you'll need to add a strategy to the include `strategy: depend`. [see last example](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/parent_child_pipelines.html#examples)

Comment: Thanks. `The 'trigger-deploy' job needs a dependency of the 'build' job` Could you please post a code example? You mean, there is a `need: []` missing?

Comment: `need: []` if your using DAG, `dependencies:` if your not. Added a link to the answer

Comment: @user3142695 I also come across the same problem. Are you able to access parent artifacts from the child stage?

Comment: Not a recent post, but this is worth I'm following up on. When using Trigger, the `dependencies` is not a valid avaialble. This accepted answer is not correct.....

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/?query=trigger:include#trigger

Answer (score 13):

We can define in child pipeline jobs to read the artefact from parent pipeline job.

First change needed is to define the PARENT_PIPELINE_ID while triggering child pipeline

```
  variables:
    PARENT_PIPELINE_ID: $CI_PIPELINE_ID
```

So, your code will change to

```
trigger-deploy:
  stage: deployment
  trigger:
    include:
      - artifact: deployment.yml
        job: build
  variables:
    PARENT_PIPELINE_ID: $CI_PIPELINE_ID
```

Now in the child pipeline, you have to use the parent pipeline id and the job which generates the artefact you need.

This can be done by adding, below to your job in child pipeline

```
  needs:
    - pipeline: $PARENT_PIPELINE_ID
      job: build
```

So, your code changes to

```
stages:
  - deploy

app1-deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - ls dist # fails, as dist folder is not existing
  needs:
    - pipeline: $PARENT_PIPELINE_ID
      job: build
```

Refer GitLab Documentation: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#needspipelinejob

Comment: Can confirm this works...The answer above is the same link, but the code here is helpful

Comment: Also works for passing environment variables (artifacts: reports: dotenv: build.env) to a child pipeline!

Answer (score 3):

`needs:pipeline:job`

A child pipeline can download artifacts from a job in its parent pipeline or another child pipeline in the same parent-child pipeline hierarchy.

Documented here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#needspipelinejob